# Sending a Flutter push notification with a URL from Firebase Cloud Messaging console

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

Is there anyway to send a URL via push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging console? I cant seem to find any clear guide regarding this for a Flutter app btw

[image]

Comment: you should be able to send that in data field of notification.

Comment: @VivekMishra theres no data field in the notification in console...check the pic, Ive updated my question

Comment: You can send in `Notification text` or use `Additional options (optional)`

Comment: @RavinderKumar how can I do it in Additional options? theres a custom data there but I dont know the key and value if I want to send a URL.

mind you that im just testing Flutter push notifications

Comment: You can declare your own key value and try to get those in your app. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send like below image,

[image]

---

Or you can pass custom data,

[image]

*This custom data is Key/value pairs that will be delivered with the message to your app.*

Comment: thanks for this one! so the key is url and the value is the link right?

Comment: just read your reply. Got it! last question then I should just use this custom key to display the link in my app right ?

Comment: Yes, you can use key-value pair as per your need.

Comment: Can you help me with my flutter problem?

Comment: do you know the syntax to display the custom data using the ```key``` and ```value``` to use it within the app?

Comment: hi @Ravinder, can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608856/display-custom-data-from-firebase-cloud-messaging-console-to-flutter-app