# Display Custom Data from Firebase Cloud Messaging console to Flutter app?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-layout

Hi is there any way to use the `key` and `value` that I've set in my Firebase Cloud Messaging console, `Additional Options` for push notification to DISPLAY inside my Flutter app?

I'm having a hard time making this work tbh, Example, I've used a `url` for key and a link for my value in my FCM console.

> What I exactly want is like this: When I send a push notification, it display to a custom screen/url_launcher/widget  within my app and that screen/url_launcher/widget shows the data I've inputted in FCM console using the **KEY** and **VALUE** that I've set when sending the push notification.

The problem is how do I display this data in my app? how do I use those key and value?
I'm kinda lost with how to code it tbh

below is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();


@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  firebaseCloudMessagingListeners();
}
void firebaseCloudMessagingListeners() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) iOSPermission();

  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
    print(token);
  });

  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on message $message');

    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on resume $message');
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on launch $message');
    },
  );
}

void iOSPermission() {
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
      .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings)
  {
    print("Settings registered: $settings");
  });
}



  WebViewController _myController;
      final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                  body: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://syncshop.online/en/',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
          onPageFinished: (controller) async {
          (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
            (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('st_notification_1').style.display='none';");
            (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('sidebar_box').style.display='none';");
          },
          ),
    floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              controller.data.reload();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          );
          }
          return Container();
        }
        ),
          ),
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you should send Custom data from the console,

[image]

You can receive the notification like this,

```
   _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("$message");
```

Output

> {notification: {title: rrakkk, body: wer}, data: {url: stackoverflow}}

**How to fetch `url` value from above?**

```
 print("${message['data']['url']}");
```

Output

> stackoverflow

Comment: Hi question, where did you get the ```fcmConfigure``` ?

Comment: and is there any way to display this custom datas to a widget AFTER the user clicks the notification ?

Comment: This is just a print tag you can take it whatever you want, the actual value is  $message

Comment: Ok thanks. But is it not possible to display this data in a widget after a user clicks the notification ?

Comment: It is possible! To display notification use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications), you can then use `onSelectNotification`

Comment: Okay! ill try looking at the package you get. Thank you!

Comment: im trying it now, btw how do I use flutter local notifications and onSelectNotification? I mean, where do I input them in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205419/discussion-between-ravinder-kumar-and-kyla-dc).